# Use C++ std::hash built-in specialization for plain integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, stl

I have data in form of arrays of 16-bit integers:

```
uint16_t a[n]
```

I need a hash function to store such data into an `unordered_set`. Now the standard library provides a built-in specialization for strings (`string`, `u8string`, `u16string`, ...). What I'm doing is:

```
std::hash<std::u16string>{}(std::u16string((char16_t*)a, n))
```

Is there a way to use the underlying hash function without the overhead of creating and destroying a string object, and without implementing an explicit hash algorithm (probably worse than the standard one)?

EDIT: I was thinking of something like a generic hash specialization taking a couple of iterators, but it does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what `std::basic_string_view` is for. There are specialized types as one might expect, one of which is `std::u16string_view`.

Pass the constructor the pointer and a length. Then you can hash the resulting object.

Comment: Isn't that creating an object as well? I understand it's a simpler object, but it seems to me that a basic iterator-based form is missing, unlike the STL philosophy.

Comment: Because different types need not be hashed the same way. The standard doesn't mandate any specific algorithm be used, just that the results are stable. For example, a numeric type that matches the size and signedness of the resulting hash value is an identity operation. It creates an object semantically but after optimizations most, if not all, of the overhead associated with string views are optimized away, leaving just the hash dispatch.

Comment: @m.alessandrini Constructing a `std::string` is expensive because it does `new`, copy, and `delete`, not because it is an object. `string_view` is a lightweight wrapper of a pointer and an integer. When compiler optimizations are enabled, `foo(std::string_view)` and `foo(const char*, size_t)` often compile to identical or almost identical machine code.